# Missing Number Algorithm Timeout Error (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, big-o, nested-loops

I'm working on a Codewars Kata that is passing all tests, except it keeps timing out.  Can anyone offer advice on how to optimize this?  Thanks in advance! 
 Here is the question breakdown -

> In this kata, we have an unsorted sequence of consecutive numbers from a to b, such that a < b always (remember a, is the minimum, and b the maximum value).
>
> They were introduced an unknown amount of duplicates in this sequence and we know that there is an only missing value such that all the duplicate values and the missing value are between a and b, but never coincide with them.
>
> Find the missing number with the duplicate numbers (duplicates should be output in a sorted array).
>
> Let's see an example:
>
> arr = [10,9,8,9,6,1,2,4,3,2,5,5,3]
>
> find_dups_miss([10,9,8,9,6,1,2,4,3,2,5,5,3]) == [7,[2,3,5,9]]

And here is my solution -

```js
function findDupsMiss(arr) {
  let missingNum = [];
  let newArr = [];
  arr = arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);
  let dup = [...new Set(arr)];
  for (let y = 1; y < dup.length; y++) {
    if (dup[y] - dup[y - 1] != 1) missingNum.push(dup[y] - 1)
  } 
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
      if (arr[i] === arr[j]) newArr.push(arr[i])
    }
  }
  missingNum.push(newArr);
  return missingNum;
}
```

Comment: If your array is sorted, you can find missing numbers and duplications in linear complexity. Just remember the last seen value. Check if what is next is the same or grater than 1. Does It ring a bell?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a Kata, meant to be solved by *you* not by *random guys on the internet*

Comment: This question is off-topic

Comment: @JonasWilms feel free!

Comment: @storaged Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could take the power of an object and the standard sorting of keys who could be used as indices of an array (positive 32 bit numbers).

This attempt has two parts

1. count all numbers
2. iterate all keys of the object with their appearances and

   1. check if it has the missing number between the actual item and the previous item. If so, assign the missing values,
   2. check the count and push the key if the count is greater than one.

This code completes in 7410 ms.

```
function findDupsMiss(arr) {
    var hash = Object.create(null),
        i = arr.length,
        l,
        v,
        keys,
        missing,
        dupes = [],
        previous, item;

    while (i--) {
        v = arr[i];
        if (!hash[v]) {
            hash[v] = 0;
        }
        hash[v]++;
    }
    keys = Object.keys(hash);
    l = keys.length;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        item = +keys[i];
        if (previous + 1 !== item) {
            missing = previous + 1;
        }        
        if (hash[item] > 1) {
            dupes.push(item);
        }
        previous = item;
    }
    return [missing, dupes];
}
```